# CSV Helper conditionally apply Membermap for child object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, csvhelper

I am using the CSV Helper library to map CSV data to my entity objects and then use entity to create the records in my database.

The map is working great for new objects. Where I have an existing child object it is creating the child object, this leads to a duplicate key name in entity.

I would like to conditionally apply the creation of the child member map based on if the location id exists or is empty.

This will allow my entity code to execute

```cs
public sealed class StopCsvMapper : ClassMap<Stop>
{
    public StopCsvMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id").Default(Guid.Empty);
        Map(m => m.Identifier).Name("Identifier");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");               
        Map(m => m.LocationId).Name("LocationId").Default(Guid.Empty);

        References<StopLocationCsvMapper>(m => m.Location);
    }
}

public class StopLocationCsvMapper : ClassMap<Location>
{
    public StopLocationCsvMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("LocationId").Default(Guid.Empty);
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("LocationName");
        Map(m => m.Notes).Name("LocationNotes");
        Map(m => m.Latitude).Name("LocationLatitude");
        Map(m => m.Longitude).Name("LocationLongitude");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just bring in the records using CsvHelper, loop through them, check the database if they exist and then delete the records that already exist?  Do that before attaching them to the EF context and/or saving them using EF.

Comment: I had hopped to do something like that. The problem is the CSVHelper on initialise creates the reference map to  the locations object. I do not know how to clear this locations object either de reference the map to locations or set the locations object to null

Answer (score 0):

This should conditionally create the child record only when the LocationId is empty.

```cs
public sealed class StopCsvMapper : ClassMap<Stop>
{
    public StopCsvMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("Id").Default(Guid.Empty);
        Map(m => m.Identifier).Name("Identifier");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");

        Map(m => m.Location).ConvertUsing(row =>
        {
            if (row.GetField("LocationId") != string.Empty)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Location
                {
                    Id = Guid.Empty,
                    Name = row.GetField("LocationName"),
                    Notes = row.GetField("LocationNotes"),
                    Latitude = row.GetField("LocationLatitude"),
                    Longitude = row.GetField("LocationLongitude"),
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```